# Error in checking if array members are prime or not

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, conditional-statements, primes

I'm supposed to scan an integer array, and loop through it, printing "Prime" or "Not prime" depending on whether the integer is a prime number or not.
It's correct in some cases, while wrong on others (like 33 as an example). Here's my code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaring the scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Getting the number of integers to scan
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        //Declaring a numbers array
        int[] numbers = new int[n];

        //Scanning the integers
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();

        //Determining if numbers are prime
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for(int j=2; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(numbers[i] % j == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    System.out.println("Not prime");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime)
                System.out.println("Prime");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why are looping till ```n``` Isn't n the number of integers you are checking if they are prime or not? You should loop till ```numbers[i]/2```

Comment: Refactor your code, and you'll likely fix the bug. Write a method `boolean isPrime(int number)` and call it in your method. Smaller, simpler methods leve much less room for bugs like the one you have. Also, use the foreach loop. once again, less room for bugs.

Comment: Or `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numbers[i]));`

Comment: Or check till `j * j <= n`. Better way is to precompute primes upto a certain range using [sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni I was just trying to get it to work for the, I was going to do the division by two to optimize my code, but later.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I want to accept your answer, I just need to understand the square root of the number thing.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I will. One thing to add, your answer doesn't work with certain inputs. Like 256 or 289 or 324 and also 1. Is something wrong with my code or yours?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It works now. What was the problem?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I've accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two important points you can consider:

**A.** You need to check numbers up to its square root i.e. if an integer is not divisible by any integer from 2 to its square root, it is Prime

**B.** You do not need an additional `boolean` flag (i.e. `isPrime` in your code).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declaring the scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Getting the number of integers to scan
        System.out.print("How many numbers: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        // Declaring a numbers array
        int[] numbers = new int[n];

        // Scanning the integers
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        // Determining if numbers are prime
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int j, upperRange = (int) Math.sqrt(numbers[i]);
            for (j = 2; j <= upperRange; j++)
                if (numbers[i] % j == 0)
                    break;
            if (numbers[i] != 1 && j > upperRange)
                System.out.println(numbers[i] + " is Prime");
            else
                System.out.println(numbers[i] + " is not Prime");
        }

    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
How many numbers: 5
Enter number 1: 256
Enter number 2: 289
Enter number 3: 1
Enter number 4: 5
Enter number 5: 7
256 is not Prime
289 is not Prime
1 is not Prime
5 is Prime
7 is Prime
```

Answer (score 0):

> Consolidating the code and using Math.sqrt() 
>   Refactor your code to to this

```
public boolean isPrime(int number){
 if(number==1){
  return false;
 }
 boolean isPrime = true;
 int maxN = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number));
 for(int j=2; j< maxN; j++){
  if(number % j == 0){
    isPrime = false;
    break;
  } 
 }
 return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: Please add a summary why your code works properly. Also, format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declaring the scanner
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Getting the number of integers to scan
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    //Declaring a numbers array
    int[] numbers = new int[n];

    //Scanning the integers
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();

    //Determining if numbers are prime
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        checkPrime(numbers[i]);
    }

}

private static void checkPrime(int number) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    int limit = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number));
    for(int j=2; j<=limit; j++)
    {
        if(number >2 && number % j == 0){
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(number> 1 && isPrime)
        System.out.println(number + " is Prime");
    else
         System.out.println(number + " is not prime");

}
```

}

Sample output

```
> 5 
> 1 2 3 4 33

1 is not prime
2 is Prime
3 is Prime
4 is not prime
33 is not prime
```